# Append Texture Coordinates

Tags: texturing, append, coordinates

I have a chessboard object that I've appended to the file. However, no matter what I do I can't edit the behavior of the texture coordinates. 3d Texture view and UV window clearly show the appropriate coordinates, but the render clearly has old coordinates.

I tried deleting the textures and making new ones by selecting the same images in the file browser pop-up(switch-up). No change. I also duplicated the object and deleted the original; 'no change (not sure if all this is silly).

I'll add a link to the file tonight, as soon as I can connect to the internet with the other machine/have access to thumb drive.

Answer (score 4):

are you using cycles, BI, or something else?

For cycles, you might have to add a *texture coordinates* node.
For BI, you might have to switch the coordinates to be UV in the image mapping section.

Comment: ctdabomb has a point.  Just because you see a texture in the 3D view doesn't mean your materials are set up correctly.  You might want to create a second scene where you have a bunch of square meshes with UV coordinates to test each of your materials.  Once you get the materials working on the squares, the original scene will probably render properly.

Comment: Ha! yes! So funny that that didn't occur to me. there's been so much integration with the last several releases, I forgot there was a time when working on game textures was a completely different deal.

Thanks guys!